# Criei um executavel com pyinstaller e ele não executa

Tags: pyinstaller

Olá

Criei um executavel com o

```
pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile -c app.py
```

conteudo do arquivo `app.py`

```
print("hello world")

x = input("Qual seu nome?")

print(x)
```

depois de gerado ao abrir o .exe ele não executa, não dá erro e nem aparece no Gerenciador de Tarefas do windows

```
python== 3.8.0
pyinstaller == 3.6


100 INFO: UPX is not available.
100 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\...\teste pyinstaller',
 'C:\\...\\teste pyinstaller']
100 INFO: checking Analysis
125 INFO: checking PYZ
156 INFO: checking PKG
156 INFO: Building because C:\...\teste pyinstaller\build\hello\hello.exe.manifest changed
156 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
1845 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
1845 INFO: Bootloader c:\...programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
1845 INFO: checking EXE
1861 INFO: Rebuilding EXE-00.toc because pkg is more recent
1861 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
1861 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\...\teste pyinstaller\dist\hello.exe
1892 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: Sempre vejo os videos do Código fonte tv onde ele usam o pyinstaller, só que no meu caso não funciona

Comment: No seu final do seu código adicione um input
Ex.:
input("Tecle enter para sair! ") No meu caso deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

não sei responder como resolver no pyinstaller mas você pode tentar usar o cx_Freeze.

Seguindo estes passos: (Python 3.6)

1 - Instalando cx_Freeze, (abra o prompt de comando e digite: *pip install cx_Freeze*).

2 - Instalando idna, (*pip install idna*).

3 - Crie um novo arquivo .py chamado setup.py na mesma pasta do seu arquivo app.py

4 - Dentro de setup.py, copie o código abaixo e o salve.

5 - Com shift pressionado clique com o botão direito dentro do diretório do arquivo app.py
e abra a janela do prompt de comando (cmd)

6 - No prompt, digite: *python setup.py build*

7 - Se seu script executar sem erros, então não houve nenhum problemas em criar o
executável. Veja na pasta onde está o arquivo principal, deverá haver outra pasta
chamada build, com outra pasta dentro, nela você deverá encontrar o arquivo app.exe.

Código para o arquivo **setup.py**

```
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    
    base = None    
    
    executables = [Executable("myfirstprog.py", base=base)]

    packages = ["idna"]
    options = {
        'build_exe': {    
            'packages':packages,
        },    
    }

    setup(
        name = "<any name>",
        options = options,
        version = "<any number>",
        description = '<any description>',
        executables = executables
    )
```

Lembre-se de modificar os atributos dentro do setup.py, principalmente "Executable('aquionomedoseuarquivo.py')" e outros como: name, version, description.

Comment: Obrigado, vou verificar

Comment: Filé "setup.py", line 7

Comment: packages= ["idna"] invalid syntax

Comment: Deu certo faltou um ]

Answer (score -2):

Pode ser que os modulos necessario nao estejam sendo importados
abra o prompt na pasta onde esta o seu projeto digite pip freeze requirements
vai aparecer uma lista de imports que sao necessarios para o seu programa funcionar
voce precisa importar eles quando for usar o pyinstaller, o comando para compilar vai ficar da seguinte forma

pyinstaller --hidden-import='nome_do_pacote' --hidden-import='nome_do_pacote'... -F seuprograma.py

logo coloque --hidden-import= xxxxx para cada pacote que apareceu la no comando freeze no final voce pode usar o -F ou o --onefile para gerar 1 arquivo standalone e por fim o nome do seu programa.py e enter.